# Bytes to string conversion in Python doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Why in Python 3 would the following code

```
print(str(b"Hello"))
```

output `b'Hello'` instead of just `Hello` as it happens with regular text strings? It looks like ultimately explicit, would-be-easy creating a `str` object from the most related binary string type is so counter-intuitive.

Comment: It prints `Hello` in py2 but `b'Hello'` in py3.

Comment: @BhargavRao: that's because in Python 2, `b'Hello'` is *already a string*. `b''` is just an alias for `''`, for forward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `bytes.__str__` is **not defined**, so `bytes.__repr__` is used instead, when you use `str()` on the object. Note that `print()` *also* calls `str()` on objects passed in, so the call is entirely redundant here.

If you are expecting text, decode explicitly instead:

```
print(b'Hello'.decode('ascii'))
```

The [`str()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) can handle `bytes` objects explicitly, but only if (again) you provide an explicit codec to decode the bytes with first:

```
print(str(b'Hello', 'ascii'))
```

The documentation is *very explicit* about this behaviour:

> If neither *encoding* nor *errors* is given, `str(object)` returns `object.__str__()`, which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a `__str__()` method, then `str()` falls back to returning `repr(object)`.
>
> If at least one of *encoding* or errors is given, *object* should be a *bytes-like object* (e.g. `bytes` or `bytearray`). In this case, if object is a `bytes` (or `bytearray`) object, then `str(bytes, encoding, errors)` is equivalent to `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`.

and

> Passing a `bytes` object to `str()` **without the encoding or errors arguments** falls under the first case of returning the informal string representation.

*Emphasis mine*.

Comment: So I do get a Unicode text string from `str(b"Hello")` but its contents are simply confusing?

Comment: @DesmondHume: you get a **representation**. A debugging tool. You get the same information for any other object that implements a helpful `__repr__` representation. For `bytes` that is a string that lets you recreate the exact same value in another Python script or in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: One thing to know about it is that if you run Python with `-b` option such cases cause warnings or errors if using `-bb` option.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want this to "work"? A bytes object is a bytes object, and its string representation in Python 3 is on that form. You can convert it's contents to a proper text string (in Python3 - which in Python2 would be "unicode" objects) you have to *decode* it to text.

And for that you need to know the encoding -

Try the following instead:

```
print(b"Hello".decode("latin-1"))
```

Note the assumed "latin-1" text codec which will translate transparently codes not in ASCII range (128-256) to unicode. It is the codec used by default by Windows for western-European languages.

The "utf-8" codec can represent a much larger range  of characters, and is the preferred encoding for international text - but if your byte string is not properly composed of utf-8 characters you might have an UnicodeDecode error on the process.

Please read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to proper undestand what text is about.

Answer (score 0):

Beforehand, sorry for my English...

Hey, I had this problem some weeks ago. It works as the people above said.
Here is a tip if the exceptions of the decoding process do not matter. In this case you can use:

```
bytesText.decode(textEncoding, 'ignore')
```

Ex:

```
>>> b'text \xab text'.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')  # Using UTF-8 is nice as you might know!
'text  text'                                     # As you can see, the « (\xab) symbol was
                                                 # ignored :D
```